# Azure: Role for Setting User Response in Alerts

Tags: azure

In our subscription we have a group of users who should be able to set the User Reponse of any alert. Which role should I assign to them - Log Monitoring Reader seems not to be appropriate?

[image]

Comment: For managing alerts, including setting the User Response, the appropriate role would typically be one of the following:

Monitoring Contributor: This role allows for reading and writing monitoring data, but not for managing access to Azure resources.

Monitoring Metrics Publisher: This role can publish metrics into Azure Metric Store, but is generally more restricted than Monitoring Contributor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create a custom role in Azure that allows a group of users to set the user response on alerts via the Azure Portal, follow these steps:

Go to the [Azure Portal](https://portal.azure.com/) and log in with your credentials.
On the left-hand side menu, click on “All services”.
In the list of services, search for and select “Subscriptions”.

[image]

From the list of subscriptions, click on the subscription where you want to create the custom role.
In the subscription's blade, look for the "Access control (IAM)" option and click on it.
[image]

Within the "Access control (IAM)" blade, click on "+ Add" and select "Add custom role" from the dropdown menu. You will be taken to the "Custom role" creation page. Click on "Start from scratch" if you want to create a new role without any pre-defined permissions.

Enter a name for your custom role, such as "Alert Response Contributor".
Optionally, provide a description for the role to explain its purpose, like "Allows setting the user response on alerts."
[image]

Click "Next" to go to the permissions section.
Click on "Add permissions".
In the "Select permissions" panel, use the search box to find the specific permissions you need.

Search for “Alerts” and select the following permissions:
-   `Microsoft.AlertsManagement/alerts/read`
-   `Microsoft.AlertsManagement/alerts/write`

Click "Add" at the bottom of the panel once you have selected the permissions.
[image]

Click "Next" to go to the assignable scopes section.
Here you can specify where this role can be assigned. For instance, if you want it to be assignable to the entire subscription, you will leave the default setting which includes your subscription's scope.

Click "Add scope" if you want to make the role available for assignment in other subscriptions or resource groups.
[image]

Click "Next" to review the role and its settings.
Check all the information to ensure it’s correct. Make sure the selected permissions and scopes match your requirements.
[image]

If everything looks good, click "Create" to create the custom role.
It might take a few moments for the role to be created and available for assignment.

Once the custom role is created, you need to assign it to the users or groups who need it within the "Access control (IAM)" blade, click on "+ Add role assignment".
[image]
In the "Role" drop-down menu, select the custom role you just created.
In the "Select" field, choose the user, group, service principal, or managed identity you want to assign the role to.
After selecting the appropriate identities, click "Save" to apply the role assignment.
[image]

Now Log in as a user who has been assigned the new role.
and try to set the user response on an alert to verify that the permissions are effective. By following these steps, you have created a custom role that allows a group of users to set the user response on alerts in Azure, and you've assigned that role to the appropriate users or groups.

Reference Document:
[MS Doc 1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/custom-roles)
[MS Doc 2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/role-assignments-alert)
[MS Doc 3](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/custom-roles-portal)